# I need to write a list to txt in Python, including text as first column and digit in second one. the first column text has different size

Tags: python, string, list, file, text

I need to write a list to txt in Python, including text as first column and digit in second one. the first column text has different size so the final results is not in order. I need to be columnwised but it is as follow:

```
Can Velocity                    0.02            m/hr
Annulus Velocity            0.03            m/hr
Tube-sheet Velocity         0.18            m/hr
Media Velocity                  0.0         m/hr
```

How to put all in correct position like:

```
Can Velocity                    0.02            m/hr
Annulus Velocity            0.03            m/hr
Tube-sheet Velocity         0.18            m/hr
Media Velocity                  0.0         m/hr
```

my code:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\---\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Report.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\t\t\t\t\FALIZ CONESH FARAND COMPANY \n"+"\t\t\t\t Address\n"
            "THESE ARE PARAMETERS CALCULATED FOR A HOUSING INCLUDING FILTER ELEMENTS \n"+
            "     \n"+
            "\t\t\t\t\t HOUSING PARAMETERS: \n")
    i=0
    for line in Parameters[0]:
        f.write(str(line)+"\t\t\t"+str(Parameters[1][i])+"\t\t\t"+Parameters[2][i])
        f.write('\n')
        i=i+1
```

Comment: I guess you wanted to have indentation be rendered differently. Try replacing tabs with spaces if your font/terminal typeface has a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

To align the columns properly in your text file, you can use Python's string formatting capabilities. Given that your first column texts have varying lengths, the best approach is to determine the maximum length of the strings in the first column and then use that length to format each line so that the second column starts at the same position in every line.

You can achieve this by using formatted string literals (f-strings) with the alignment option, or the str.format() method. Here's an example using f-strings:

```
# Sample data
Parameters = [["Can Velocity", "Annulus Velocity", "Tube-sheet Velocity", "Media Velocity"],
                      [0.02, 0.03, 0.18, 0.0],
                      ["m/hr", "m/hr", "m/hr", "m/hr"]]

# Find the maximum length of the strings in the first column
max_length = max(len(item) for item in Parameters[0])

with open('C:\\Users\\---\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Report.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\t\t\t\t\FALIZ CONESH FARAND COMPANY \n" + "\t\t\t\t Address\n"
            "THESE ARE PARAMETERS CALCULATED FOR A HOUSING INCLUDING FILTER ELEMENTS \n"
            "     \n"
            "\t\t\t\t\t HOUSING PARAMETERS: \n")
    
    for i in range(len(Parameters[0])):
        line = Parameters[0][i]
        value = Parameters[1][i]
        unit = Parameters[2][i]
        formatted_line = f"{line:<{max_length}} {value} {unit}"
        f.write(formatted_line + '\n')
```

This code will align all the values in the second and third columns, regardless of the length of the text in the first column. The :<{max_length} in the f-string is used for left-aligning the text within a field of width max_length. This ensures that all the subsequent columns start at the same position.